# How can you run profiling on a Java application wrapped as an .exe?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm, jstatd

I would like to run profiling using `jstatd` and `visualvm` against a third-party Java application which has been wrapped as an `.exe`. Does anybody have advice on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special. Just run VisualVM locally under the same user as your Java application. It does not matter that it is wrapped as .exe file. What version of JDK does you application use?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you aren't quite right. I am profiling two Java apps which are each wrapped as `.exe` files. Each runs in a Jetty container (as they are really webapps). I don't see them via `jps` and they aren't visible in `visualvm` either. I can only run profiling when I run them in a standalone Jetty as `war` files.

Comment: Are you sure that they run under the same user? Maybe those .exe files  run as Windows service.

Comment: Tomas, you are right, they are running as a service. What would you advise me to check? (I am a Unix/Linux guy and Windows is really not my forte).

Comment: Please check the following article: https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/monitoring_java_processes_running_as . It summarizes different possibilities for monitoring java Windows services with VisualVM.